# Unreal Engine 4 : Converting DrawMesh() from Unity

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am new to the Unreal Engine UE4 and I want to convert my existing code. Can anybody help?

```
Material material = Resources.Load ("Meshes/Materials/" + files [index] + "material_0", typeof(Material)) as Material;
Texture2D texture = Resources.Load ("Textures/" + files [index], typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
Mesh[] meshes = Resources.LoadAll ("Meshes/" + files [index], typeof(Mesh)).Cast<Mesh> ().ToArray ();
for (int m = 0; m < meshes.Length; m++) {
    Graphics.DrawMesh (meshes [m], matrix, material, 0);
}
```

Comment: How this topic is realted to Unity3D?

Comment: He would like to port his existing Unity3D C# code to UE4 C++ code....

Comment: true! I would like to do the same stuff in Unreal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, such code must be placed at the constructor of the class.
Also you need to bDontLoadBlueprintOutsideEditor to false at DefaultEditor.ini cause if it set to false, your release app with crash with cannot found blueprint class.
Of course you can add custom material with GetMesh()

```
static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<USkeletalMesh> AssignableMesh(TEXT("/Game/Units/Characters/UNT_Sol_01/UNT_Solder_01"));

static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UPhysicsAsset> AssignablePhysics(TEXT("/Game/Units/Characters/UNT_Sol_01/UNT_Solder_01_PhysicsAsset"));

static ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UAnimBlueprint> AssignableABP(TEXT("/Game/Units/Characters/UNT_Sol_01/UNT_ABP"));

WeaponAttachment = AM4Weapon::StaticClass();

GetMesh()->bReceivesDecals = false;
GetMesh()->MeshComponentUpdateFlag = EMeshComponentUpdateFlag::AlwaysTickPoseAndRefreshBones;
GetMesh()->SetSkeletalMesh(AssignableMesh.Object);
GetMesh()->SetRelativeRotation(FRotator(0.0f, -90.0f, 0.0f));
GetMesh()->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f));
GetMesh()->SetPhysicsAsset(AssignablePhysics.Object);
GetMesh()->SetAnimInstanceClass(AssignableABP.Object->GeneratedClass);
GetMesh()->SetRelativeScale3D(FVector(3.0f));
```